# kolmogorov-Smirnov Test Java

Tags: java, statistics

I need help in choosing the best library to implement the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test (Two-Sample) in Java.

I have tried using [JavaStatisticalClass](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/index.html).

Problem with this library is that I can't specify/choose the "Significance Level" by myself.

Do you have any suggestions of other libraries where I can chose the significance level?

Comment: @Ebermann, Rhetorical question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the significance level a priori you can determine the p-value using JavaStatisticalClass and compare this value with the intended significance.

Answer (score 1):

How about jsc.goodnessfit.KolmogorovTest?